ASP.NET Core / EF Core / Mysql - how to group by week?
I'm new to ASP.NET Core and working on a project where I need to group data by week using Entity Framework Core (EF Core) with a MySQL database. However, I'm encountering an issue with the grouping.
Here's the LINQ query I'm using:
from report in _context.DmarcReports
    .Where(r => r.DomainName == request.Domain)
    .Where(r => !request.BeginDate.HasValue || r.BeginDate >= request.BeginDate.Value)
    .Where(r => !request.EndDate.HasValue || r.EndDate <= request.EndDate.Value)
join summary in _context.DmarcSummary 
     on report.ReportId equals summary.ReportId
join sourceLookup in _context.SourceLookup 
     on summary.SourceIp equals sourceLookup.Ip
let week = EF.Functions.DateDiffWeek(
  EF.Functions.DateFromParts(report.BeginDate.Year, 1, 1), 
  report.BeginDate
) + 1  
let year = report.BeginDate.Year
group summary by new { sourceLookup.SourceName, Week = week, Year = year } into g
select new
{
    Date = EF.Functions.DateFromParts(g.Key.Year, 1, 1),
    Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, 1, 1).AddDays((g.Key.Week - 1) * 7),
    SourceName = g.Key.SourceName,
    DMARCPassCount = g.Sum(x => x.DMARCVolume),
}

I'm trying to use EF.Functions.DateDiffWeek() to calculate the week number for grouping. However, I'm getting the following error:

'DbFunctions' does not contain a definition for 'DateDiffWeek' and no accessible extension method 'DateDiffWeek' accepting a first argument of type 'DbFunctions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've already added the necessary using directives:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Do you really use a MySQL database? Those functions DateDiffWeek and also DateFromParts are functions for a SQL Server DB. So I assume you need to use other functions supported by MySQL. Or do you use MSSQL and not MySQL?

See also the documentation about MySQL date functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html Yes, I know you use Entity Framework that can translate some functions "inside" and run them on other RDBMS, too, but some functions still work on exactly the RDBMS they have been created for.

@JonasMetzler I use Mysql database.

Then I would try to use functions listed in the linked documentation

Pomelo seems to have surfaced what you want (only just currently it seems so check if you use the most current version of Pomelo). But DateFromParts still is SqlServer specific. The equivalent for that would be MakeDate in MySql and that is not surfaced (at least i didn't see that). So you have to surface it yourself.

@Ralf surfacing means ?

That the functionality of MySql has been made available in .Net as a method. It has been surfaced to you.

@AdiLIsmaiL the typical way used in all databases is to use a Calendar table, join with it and group by the Month, Week, Semester, Trimester or any other reporting period field you want. That's the typical way to generate time-based reports in all reporting databases and data warehouses

@AdiLIsmaiL You don't have to perform the JOIN in LINQ either, in fact that's a terrible idea. You can create a view that joins with the Calendar table or Date dimension and map to it. ORMs like EF are meant to load graphs of objects, not generate complex reporting queries.

from report in _context.DmarcReports
.Where(r => r.DomainName == request.Domain)
.Where(r => !request.BeginDate.HasValue || r.BeginDate >= request.BeginDate.Value)
.Where(r => !request.EndDate.HasValue || r.EndDate <= request.EndDate.Value) join summary in _context.DmarcSummary 
 on report.ReportId equals summary.ReportId join sourceLookup in _context.SourceLookup 
 on summary.SourceIp equals sourceLookup.Ip let weekDifference = (report.BeginDate - new DateTime(report.BeginDate.Year, 1, 1)).Days / 7 + 1 let year = report.BeginDate.Year group summary by new { sourceLookup.SourceName, Week = weekDifference, Year = year } into g select new {
Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, 1, 1).AddDays((g.Key.Week - 1) * 7),
SourceName = g.Key.SourceName,
DMARCPassCount = g.Sum(x => x.DMARCVolume),};


In this modified query, weekDifference calculates the week difference between the report.BeginDate and the first day of the year. This value is then used for grouping. The rest of the query remains unchanged.

This should resolve the issue and allow you to group the data by week effectively.
